# How to open a text file in a rails gem and insert its output into a view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm making a ruby gem (with standard directory structure e.g., lib/mygem)...Within that gem, I have a method call that is supposed to open a css file (from lib/vendor/assets/css in the gem directory structure). and output the css to a view file.  mygem.rb looks like:

```
require "mygem/version"
 module MyGem
   class Engine < Rails::Engine #cause rails to add its directories to the load path when the gem is required.
   end
 def mygem_div_tag(div_id, options={})
     options = {:css_template=>"example1"}.merge(options)
    file_str = IO.read("../vendor/assets/css/"+options[:css_template]+".css")
    div_str = %Q{
   <style type="text/css">
  #{file_str}
  </style> }
 end
```

So in the view I would have something like the following:

```
<%= mygem_div_tag %>
```

And I get an error: *No such file or directory - ../vendor/assets/css/example1.css*

How do I output the CSS that's in the "example1.css" file?

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of a Rails app, try:

> ```
> file_str = IO.read("#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/css/"+options[:css_template]+".css")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to [`IO#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read) is either an absolute path, or a path relative to the working directory of the process, *not* relative to the current file. When your gem is running as part of another app, you won’t know either of these.

In order to get the path relative to the current file, you can use [`File#expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) along with the [`__FILE__`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__) special constant:

```
file_path = File.expand_path("../vendor/assets/css/"+options[:css_template]+".css", File.dirname(__FILE__))
file_str = IO.read(file_path)
```

Comment: thanks, this is a great contextual answer.  But I get an error: "No such file or directory - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/mygem-0.0.1/vendor/assets/css/example1.css"...This leads me to guess it has something to do with Rails not loading non-ruby files in the gem directory into working memory?  Unsure...Perhaps my approach should be to have the gem install the .css file into app/vendor/assets/css

Comment: What directory is the css file in, and what directory is your `rb` file in? It looks like the path is missing `lib`. Is your Ruby file directly in `lib`, or in a subdirectory (I’ve assumed a subdirectory in this code)?